# Is it possible to listen on the Airdrop protocol with my Ubuntu machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I know there are already some existing posts out there but they are about Macs.

So I am trying to reverse engineer Apple’s AirDrop Protocol with an Ubuntu machine. For Mac there is a program called [iStumbler](https://istumbler.net), but there isn’t a version for Linux based machines.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at reverse-engineering the AirDrop protocol, I strongly encourage you to take a look at https://owlink.org/ which have done a tremendous effort in that direction. They even have a free Python implementation called [opendrop](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/opendrop).

See also those related questions, now closed:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220136/how-the-new-mac-os-airdrop-works
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693411/implementing-the-airdrop-protocol

Answer (score -2):

You can try wireshark to monitor the local network packets.  You can set filters based on the IP address of the machine you are looking to monitor.